# adjacency matrix: reduce upper band-width

Tags: algorithm, matlab, sorting, graph-theory, adjacency-matrix

I have a binary adjacency matrix of a directed graph. Now I want to reorder it so that the number of elements above the diagonale as well as their distance to the diagonale is minimized.

To give you the application background: I m working with a task based design structure matrix. 
For example I have three tasks, A, B, C. This means that I have the rows A, B, C and accordingly the columns A, B, C. Now, if task B needs Input from task A, the element (b,a) is a one, otherwise it is zero.

The order of the tasks shows the sequence in which the tasks are performed. 
So if the input task A is performed before the input is needed by task B, the one is below the diagonale. If the ones are above the diagonale (for example if A relies on input of B), this means that the inputs will be generated in the future which is bad.

To optimize the sequence of the tasks, the matrix should be a lower tirangular matrix so that inputs are generated before they are needed. Since this is usually not possible, the optimum is to reduce the number of ones above the diagonale and also reduce the distance to the diagonale.

When reordering the matrix, it is a problem that the order of the rows and the columns need to stay the same. So if I move row A one row lower, I automatically need to move column A one column to the left.

Well, I googled and found the Cuthill-Mckee algorithm but it only works for symmetric matrices and since I am having a directed graph, my matrix is asymmetric with possible symmetric entries.

Also, the Reid-Scott algorithm just reduces the overall band-width and therefore has an unecessary constraint of the lower bandwidth.

Basically I am searching for an algorithm just minimizing the upper band-width  as all entries below the diagonale do not matter.

I hope that I could pose my question in a comprehensive way. I am not familiar with graph theory and did not study mathematics or computer science so a friendly hint would be nice.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can the tasks make a cycle? e.g, A depends on B, B depends on C, ... X depends on A

Comment: It sounds like a [scheduling problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheduling_(computing)), possibly just a [topological sorting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting) of your graph.

Comment: yes. The problem is that the task to make a cycle. This is exactly the Problem.

Comment: @beaker Yes it is a scheduling problem. But since there are cross dependencies ( as merlyn asked) it is not possible to use topological sorting. This would imply that we can create a complete lowetriangular matrix and with the matrix I am working with it is not possible. However, the idea is to move the tasks that have inter dependencies together so that they can have a small cycle within.